# I keep getting the message 'not authorized to edit pin' in my flash message box on my pinterest demo site using ruby on rails, I cant figure out why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, messagebox, pinterest, posts

I keep getting the message 'not authorized to edit this pin' in my flash message box on my pinterest demo site using ruby on rails, I cant figure out why?

I keep getting this message despite being the correct user who created the pin while logged in, but it wont let me edit or destroy it. everything else seems to work fine.

Here are my files:

**pins_controller.rb**

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
# GET /pins
# GET /pins.json
def index
  @pins = Pin.all
end
# GET /pins/1
# GET /pins/1.json
def show
end
# GET /pins/new
def new
  @pin = current_user.pins.build
end
# GET /pins/1/edit
def edit
end
# POST /pins
# POST /pins.json
def create
  @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @pin.save
      format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pin }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
# PATCH/PUT /pins/1
# PATCH/PUT /pins/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pin }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
# DELETE /pins/1
# DELETE /pins/1.json
def destroy
  @pin.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to pins_url, notice: 'Pin was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_pin
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
end
end
def correct_user
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :pins
end
```

**pin.rb**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160102054151) do
  create_table "pins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
  add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

Comment: You need to wrap the code sections in code blocks as your question is really hard to read, especially on mobile. In markdown, lines starting with `#` are headings so all your comment lines are huge.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005097

It seems like you're setting `@pin` twice, once in `set_pin` and when calling `correct_user`.